# XirSys - SimpleWebRTC - I get 'Could not validate application' when doing the request to iceServers

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

My request to xirsys endpoint looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://api.xirsys.com/getIceServers",
    data: {
        ident: "username",
        secret: "secret_api_key",
        domain: "dummy_subdomain.domain.com",
        application: "default",
        room: "default",
        secure: 1
    },
});
```

However, even if the username, secret and the rest of information seem to be correct into the `xirsys` dashboard, I get this error: `'Could not validate application'`.

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you.

---

Well, I tried this and I now get a 200 status, but unfortunately I get this response:
{"p":"/getIceServers","s":200,"d":{"iceServers":[{"url":"stun:127.0.0.1"},{"username":"free","url":"turn:127.0.0.1?transport=udp","credential":"free"},{"username":"free","url":"turn:127.0.0.1?transport=tcp","credential":"free"}]},"e":null}
Which I think is a default response.

What could I do wrong ?

Comment: You are using jQuery, isn't it ? I guess the dataType is wrong (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ say DataType could be PlainObject or String). Looking to http://xirsys.com/files/docs/index.php/Quick_Start_Guide, dataType is not specified. Did you try to remove `dataType: "json"` ?

Comment: yes, I tried, but I now get a 400 status

Comment: Making some tries, I receive `{"p":"/getIceServers","s":400,"d":null,"e":"Could not validate application"}` when the domain deosnot exists. Is your domain `dummy_subdomain.domain.com` displayed using https://my.xirsys.com/domains/list ? If not you should create it using https://my.xirsys.com/domains/create ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Can it be a subdomain ?

Comment: I tried with the same domain you used `dummy_subdomain.domain.com`, then I have no more ideas... perhaps you could recreate a new account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, XirSys doesn't support the posting of JSON to its endpoints. You'll need to change it to posting standard POST cars for it to work. JSON support will be added very soon.

Regards,
Lee